# Fragment is losing information during orientation change

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation

I am creating a simple app as a practice.

Below is the code from activityMain, mainFragment, and the xml files for my tip calculator.  When I run the app and turn my phone 90 degrees, some information stays during re-orientation as expected, and some information disappears.

I used fragments even though the app is one screen in order to deal with life cycle issues, and because most apps I work on use fragments.  I have used navigation component for the same reason.  It is my understanding that using navigation component also removes additional work with fragment managers.  Any help would be appreciated.

`//Main.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

}

```
//fragment Main

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.giftofhappiness.android.tipcalculator5.databinding.FragmentMainBinding
import java.text.DecimalFormat
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    var numberOfDiners: Int = 1



    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    var dollarFormat = DecimalFormat("#,###.00")


    var amount: Double = 0.0
    var tipAmount: Double = 0.0
    var numericTip: Double = 0.0
    var numericTotal: Double = 0.0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        binding.clrBtn.setOnClickListener {

            amount = 0.0
            tipAmount = 0.0
            numericTip = 0.0
            numericTotal = 0.0

            binding.totalTxtView.setText("")
            binding.tipTxtView.setText("")
            binding.billAmountEditTxt.setText("")

            billSplitResults(numberOfDiners)
            hideBillSplit()


        }

        binding.numberOfDinersEditTxt.text = numberOfDiners.toString()


        binding.rndBtn.setOnClickListener {

            val tipAmount : Double = numericTip


            val roundedTipAmount = tipAmount.roundToInt()

            numericTip = roundedTipAmount.toDouble()

            numericTotal = numericTip + amount

            billSplitResults(numberOfDiners)

            val stringRoundTipAmount =roundedTipAmount.toString()
            val totalAmount: Double = amount + roundedTipAmount

            val dollarTotalFormat = dollarFormat.format(totalAmount)

            val decimalFormatTip = "$$stringRoundTipAmount.00"
            val decimalFormatTotal = "$$dollarTotalFormat"




            binding.tipTxtView.setText(decimalFormatTip)
           binding.totalTxtView.setText(decimalFormatTotal)


        }

        binding.tipAmount10.setOnClickListener {

            amount = nullCheck()

            val finishedTip = getTotalTip(0.10)

            val finishedTotal = getTotalTotal(finishedTip)
            binding.tipTxtView.text = "$$finishedTip"
            binding.totalTxtView.text = "$$finishedTotal"
            billSplitResults(numberOfDiners)


        }



        binding.tipAmount15.setOnClickListener {

            amount = nullCheck()
            val finishedTip = getTotalTip(0.15)
            val finishedTotal = getTotalTotal(finishedTip)
            binding.tipTxtView.text = "$$finishedTip"
            binding.totalTxtView.text = "$$finishedTotal"
            billSplitResults(numberOfDiners)
        }

        binding.tipAmount20.setOnClickListener {

            amount = nullCheck()
            val finishedTip = getTotalTip(0.2)
            val finishedTotal = getTotalTotal(finishedTip)
            binding.tipTxtView.text = "$$finishedTip"
            binding.totalTxtView.text = "$$finishedTotal"
            billSplitResults(numberOfDiners)
        }


        binding.tipAmount25.setOnClickListener {

            amount = nullCheck()
            val finishedTip = getTotalTip(0.25)
            val finishedTotal = getTotalTotal(finishedTip)
            binding.tipTxtView.text = "$$finishedTip"
            binding.totalTxtView.text = "$$finishedTotal"
            billSplitResults(numberOfDiners)
        }


        binding.tipAmount30.setOnClickListener {

            amount = nullCheck()
            val finishedTip = getTotalTip(0.3)
            val finishedTotal = getTotalTotal(finishedTip)
            binding.tipTxtView.text = "$$finishedTip"
            binding.totalTxtView.text = "$$finishedTotal"
            billSplitResults(numberOfDiners)

        }
        //bill split section


        binding.lessDinerBtn.setOnClickListener {

            numberOfDiners.toInt()
            numberOfDiners--
            if(numberOfDiners >= 1){
                numberOfDiners=numberOfDiners
            }else{numberOfDiners=1}

            billSplitResults(numberOfDiners)

            showBillSplit()



        }

        binding.moreDinersBtn.setOnClickListener {
            numberOfDiners.toInt()
            numberOfDiners++

            if(numberOfDiners >= 1){
                numberOfDiners=numberOfDiners
            }else{numberOfDiners=1}

            billSplitResults(numberOfDiners)

            showBillSplit()

        }


    binding.billSplitBtn.setOnClickListener {

        billSplitResults(numberOfDiners)

        if(binding.billSplitBtn.text == "Bill Split"){

            showBillSplit()

            }else{
                hideBillSplit()


        }


    }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun showBillSplit() {
        binding.billSplitBtn.text = "Hide"
        binding.splitTipResult.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.splitTipTxtView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        binding.splitTotalResult.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.splitTotalTxtView.visibility= View.VISIBLE

        binding.splitBillTxtView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.splitBillResult.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun hideBillSplit() {
        binding.billSplitBtn.text ="Bill Split"
        binding.splitTipResult.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.splitTipTxtView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        binding.splitTotalResult.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.splitTotalTxtView.visibility= View.INVISIBLE

        binding.splitBillTxtView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.splitBillResult.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    private fun billSplitResults(i: Int) {

        val tipSplit = numericTip/numberOfDiners
        val billSplit = amount/numberOfDiners
        val totalSplit = numericTotal/numberOfDiners

        val formattedSplitTiP = dollarFormat.format(tipSplit)
        val formattedBillSplit = dollarFormat.format(billSplit)
        val formattedTotalSplit = dollarFormat.format(totalSplit)


        binding.numberOfDinersEditTxt.text = numberOfDiners.toString()
        binding.splitTipResult.text = "$$formattedSplitTiP"
        binding.splitBillResult.text = "$$formattedBillSplit"
        binding.splitTotalResult.text = "$$formattedTotalSplit"



    }


    private fun getTotalTotal(x: String): String {

        val doubleTotal = x.toDouble()

        val total: Double = doubleTotal + amount
        numericTotal = total
        val formattedTotal = dollarFormat.format(total)
        val finishedTotal = formattedTotal.toString()

        return finishedTotal.toString()

    }

    private fun tipNullCheck():Double{
        if(binding.tipTxtView.text.isBlank()){
            tipAmount = 0.0
        }else{
            tipAmount = binding.tipTxtView.text.toString().toDouble()
        }
        return tipAmount
    }

    private fun nullCheck(): Double {
        if (binding.billAmountEditTxt.text.isBlank()) {
            amount = 0.0
        } else {
            amount = binding.billAmountEditTxt.text.toString().toDouble()
        }

        return amount

    }

    private fun getTotalTip(x: Double): String {


        val tipAmount: Double = amount * x
        numericTip = tipAmount
        val formattedTip = dollarFormat.format(tipAmount)
        val finishedTip = formattedTip.toString()

        return finishedTip


    }



}

//fragmentMain.xml
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/amountTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Amount:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/tipAmount30"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_change_file"
        android:text="30%"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tipAmount25" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/amountBackGroundTextView"

        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_amount_box"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/billAmountEditTxt"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/billAmountEditTxt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/billAmountEditTxt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/billAmountEditTxt"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="$$$"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/amountTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/amountTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/amountTextView" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/tipAmount25"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_change_file"
        android:text="25%"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tipAmount20" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/tipAmount20"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_change_file"
        android:text="20%"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tipAmount15" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/tipAmount15"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_change_file"
        android:text="15%"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tipAmount10" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/tipAmount10"
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_change_file"
        android:text="10%"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalTxtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        tools:text="$56.78" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tipTxtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:text="$4.56" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Tip:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amountTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Total:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/rndBtn"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_change_file"
        android:text="Round"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tipTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/clrBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/totalTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tipTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/clrBtn"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_change_file"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/totalTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/totalTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/totalTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="32dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="44dp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton

        android:id="@+id/billSplitBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_change_file"
        android:text="Bill Split"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tipAmount30" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Party#:"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/billSplitBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/numberOfDinersEditTxt"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/billSplitBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/billSplitBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberOfDinersEditTxt"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lessDinerBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/lessDinerBtn"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_design"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_left_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/numberOfDinersEditTxt"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/moreDinersBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/numberOfDinersEditTxt" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/moreDinersBtn"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_design"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_right_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/lessDinerBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splitBillTxtView"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Bill Amount Per Person:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/splitTipTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitTipTxtView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splitTipTxtView"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Tip Per Person:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/billSplitBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splitTotalTxtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Total Per Person:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splitBillTxtView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splitTipResult"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:text="$$$"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/splitTipTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/splitBillResult"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/splitBillResult"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/splitTipTxtView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splitBillResult"
        android:visibility="invisible"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:text="$$$"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/splitBillTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/splitBillTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/splitBillTxtView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splitTotalResult"
        android:visibility="invisible"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$$$"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/splitTotalTxtView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/splitBillResult"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/splitBillResult"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/splitTotalTxtView" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

//activityMain.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Comment: Any properties that you want to preserve through an orientation change should be put in a ViewModel. Your various View classes should get the data they display from the ViewModel, not local Fragment or Activity properties.

Comment: Thank you sir or madam!!!  I shall do so in the morning.